# import 文でエラー SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python3

PythonでZendeskのヘルプページをエクスポートするため、以下のページを参照し、次のコードを記述しました。

[Backing up your knowledge base with the Help Center API | Zendesk Developer Docs](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/help_center/help-center-api/backing-up-your-knowledge-base-with-the-help-center-api/?_ga=2.212588564.1494336950.1693443948-1251591048.1693443948)

```
import osimport datetime
import requests
credentials = 'EXAMPLE@EMAIL.COM', 'EXAMPLEPASSWORD'
zendesk = 'https://SUBDOMAINNAME.zendesk.com'
language = 'ja=JP'

date = datetime.date.today()
backup_path = os.path.join(str(date), language)
if not os.path.exists(backup_path):
        os.makedirs(backup_path)
```

Macのターミナルを起動し、当該スクリプトが存在するディレクトリに移動した後、以下のコマンドを実行しました。

```
python3 make_backup.py
```

その結果、以下の構文エラーが表示されました。

```
File "/Users/USERNAME/make_backup.py", line 1
import osimport datetime
                ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

datetimeに関するライブラリーが入っていないのかとも思ったのですが、MacにインストールされているPythonは3.11.5のため、問題なさそうです。

このエラーを回避して、正しく実行する方法を教えてください。

Comment: `import osimport datetime`とは、本来2行に分かれているはずのものが1行に連結されてしまったのでは？ 参照リンク先では2行に分かれて記述されています。そのとおり2行に分けるか、`import os, datetime`に変更してみてください。

Comment: 神様！！ありがとうございます、無事動きました…！！

Comment: @kunif すみません、回答の承認をしたいので、回答をつけていただくことは可能でしょうか…？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントで解決したとのことで回答として書きます。

エラーメッセージに表示された`import osimport datetime`とは、本来2行に分かれているはずのものを書き写す際に1行に連結されてしまったものでしょう。
参照リンク先では2行に分かれて記述されています。

> Your script so far should look like this:
>
> ```
> 1  import os
> 2  import datetime
> 3  
> 4  import requests
> 5  
> 6  credentials = 'your_zendesk_email', 'your_zendesk_password'
> ```

以下省略

参照リンク先のとおり2行に分けるか、1行で書くなら`import os, datetime`に変更してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました！！本当に助かりました！